# Gathering Date and Time of page load, on page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a web form setup on an area of my site. I need to gather the Date and Time of when it's visited.

I'm wondering how I'd be able to code it so that, on page load, the date and time is gathered?

How could I do this? *Something with defining on page load with Javascript / jQuery > calling a PHP snippet that gathers Y = date, T = time > then I tie to store where my form is stored?*

Thanks for any suggestions, code help also appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to include it in a form, I'd use php's `date()` function:

```
<form....>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s');?>" />
...
</form>
```

This will output something like:

```
<form....>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2012-01-31" />
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="14:50:21" />
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with PHP as shown by Ben but it is really easy to do in JavaScript.

### html

```
<form...>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="" />
...
</form>
```

### javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=\"date\"]").val(+new Date());
});
```

This will populate the `date` `<input>` value with the milliseconds since 1/1/1970 (i.e. epoch). IMO it is the easiest way to deal with dates between JavaScript and other languages as most have an easy function for converting `unix timestamps` (seconds since 1/1/1970, divided JS by 1000) into the native Date format of the language.

Comment: This is good, but if the OP wants to use it for something on the server-side, this solution is not ideal, as it relies on JS for the date... which means that it relies on the client's machine. If you're trying to get the time a page was loaded for analytic use or for security, you'll want to use a server-side solution (for security you'd probably also want to encrypt the input value or store the value in sessions)

Comment: He did ask for "Something with defining on page load with Javascript / jQuery". I believe that is exactly what my example is. If you are going to do it server side the accuracy would be a bit lower, and it wouldn't reflect the time of day of the user. Personally, I would just look at the form submission time if I was going to do it all server side.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$loadtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    echo $loadtime;
```

You want to get the time on load, and put it in a variable.